# TypeScript: Get Generic function type from "typeof" generic function

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm pretty sure TypeScript has a way of doing this but I haven't figured it out yet.

Is there a way to extract a generic type from the `typeof` a generic function?

Consider this simple generic function:

```js
function echo<T> (input: T) {
   return input;
}
```

I want to extract the generic type of this function. I tried:

```js
type IEchoFn = typeof echo;
```

But it's unusable:

```js
const echo2: IEchoFn = (input: string) => input;
      ^^^^^
      // Type '(input: string) => string' is not 
      // assignable to type '<T>(input: T) => T'.
```

I thought I'd write it as

```js
type IEchoFn<T> = (typeof echo)<T>;
```

But this is invalid syntax.

How can I extract a generic type from the `typeof` a generic function (or its return value)?

Comment: You can assign a generic function to a concrete function, but not the other way round. This would work: `const echo2: (input: string) => string = echo;`

Comment: I've run into this same problem. Often times, we use packages that have functions with complex template types. Often it would be advantageous to use a `typeof fn`, but without a way to assign template types, we can't use `typeof`. It leads to some pretty ugly typings.

Comment: Relevant issue on github: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37181

Answer (score 0):

Variables that has an explicit type are set in stone and can not be inferred from its value.

This is one way to solve it:

```
type IEchoFn<T> = (input: T) => T

const echo2: IEchoFn<string> = arg => arg
```